# Don't escape encoded symbols

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, escaping, html-escape-characters

Can I disable escaping *only* for encoded characters? E.g. if I have `&#225;` I don't want to get `&amp;225;`. But having `<script>` converted to `&lt;script&gt;` would be nice :)

Eg:
I retrieve `person` from some remote sources. And `person.name` can be something like "Cristi&#225;n Romo" which is actually "Cristián Romo". So when I use

```
%header= @person.name
```

I wan't to have actual "Cristi&#225;n Romo" and not "Cristi&amp;#225;n Romo".

On the other hand I can't guarantee that person.name won't be something bad like javascript. And I'd like to keep it safe.

Moreover I don't understand how escaping encoded symbols makes code safer

Comment: please give a example of your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
%header= raw(@person.name)
```

Comment: `raw` is the same as '.html_safe`. Once again, I can't be sure that `person.name` is safe. And a don't see how encoded symbols can be unsafe.